# Cannot return protocol implementation in function that returns generic type constrained to that protocol

Tags: swift, generics

I'm having a hard time understanding this compiler error from the code below: `Cannot convert return expression of type 'TemperatureDevice' to return type 'D'`. Why won't this compile? I'm wondering if there is something fundamental to Swift Generics and Protocol associated types that I am missing.

```
protocol Device {
    associatedtype Reading
    var name: String { get }
    func getReading() -> Reading
}

protocol DeviceManager {
    func getDevice<D>() -> D where D: Device
}

struct TemperatureReading {
    let temperature: Double
}

struct TemperatureDevice: Device {
    typealias Reading = TemperatureReading
    let name: String

    func getReading() -> TemperatureReading {
        TemperatureReading(temperature: 0)
    }
}

struct TemperatureDeviceManager: DeviceManager {
    func getDevice<D>() -> D where D: Device {
        // Compiler Error: "Cannot convert value of type
        // 'TemperatureDevice' to expected element type 'D'"
        TemperatureDevice(name: "My Device")
    }
}
```

Comment: This can't work as written, because there's no guarantee that `getDevice` is called in a context where `D` is `TemperatureDevice`. Imagine if I wrote: `let iExpectAString: String = TemperatureDeviceManager().getDevice()`. How would that work? If you give some more context on what you're trying to achieve, we can try to help out with it.

Comment: `func getDevice<D>() -> D where D: Device` says that the caller gets to pick any Device type they want (of the infinite possible conforming types), and `getDevice` will return it. That function is impossible to implement (other than calling `fatalError()`). I don't see any way these protocols could be useful. It looks like you've built this backwards (probably treating protocols as abstract classes, which they aren't). Start with concrete types and concrete callers, and see where you get duplicate code; then extract protocols from that.

Comment: This is a contrived example that I paired down to simplify here; what I'm going for is a system that supports different `Device`s, each providing the ability to obtain its `Reading`s, whose type is specific to the `Device`. Once a user is logged in, the system can determine which `Device`s that user has access to (so it would really be `getDevices() -> [D] where D: Device`). OK... now that I type this out I can see how this won't work; when I go to use the returned `[D]`, even though I theoretically know that each item has `getReading()`, there's no way to know the associatetype for Reading.

Comment: @RobNapier your advice to start with concrete definitely seems wise. I'd like to have one function that returns the user's devices, but not force the caller to figure out what type each device is (so they don't have to do something like `if let device = device as? TemperatureDevice {`. It kind of jumps out at me that what I have won't work when I add a second Device-conforming type and attempt to do something like:
```
struct TemperatureDeviceManager<D: Device>: DeviceManager {
    private let devices: [D] = [TemperatureDevice(name: ""), HumidityDevice(name: "")]
    ....
}
```

Comment: Yeah, as you write the consuming code, you'll quickly discover what you need protocols for. Without knowing Reading, it's impossible for the caller to do anything. But the question is what the caller wants to do. If it's just display, then it may make sense for the protocol to return formatted Strings, for example, which would get rid of the associatedtype issues.